# How to make a pointer to a pointer NULL

Tags: c++, c, unix, pointers

I am trying to make the last element in an array of pointers a NULL but I am having some problems. My code is as follows:

```
kernel->availMsgEnvQueue = (MsgEnv *)malloc(AVAIL_MSG_ENV_SIZE * sizeof(MsgEnv));
int i;
for(i=0; i<AVAIL_MSG_ENV_SIZE-1; i++)
     {
    kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[i].nextMsgEnv = &(kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[i+1]);
    kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[i].msg = (Msg)malloc(MSG_SIZE * sizeof(char));
}
kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[19].nextMsgEnv = NULL;
```

Where AVAIL_MSG_ENV_SIZE is 20. I am trying to make the 20th element a null but this is not working as I am getting a segmentation fault when I run the following to test:

```
while (kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv) 
     {
    printf ("%d\n", x);
    temp = temp->nextMsgEnv;
    x++;
}
```

X counts all the way upto 20 and then it crashes. Please assist.

---

**EDIT :** Apparantly the last element in the list is being sent to zero. I can't figure out if this code will dequeue the last message envelope from the queue::

```
MsgEnv * k_request_msg_env (){
    MsgEnv * env = kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv;
    if(!env){
        printf ("This one was null");
        PCB * pcb = kernel->current_process;
        if(pcb->state != IS_IPROCESS){
            printf ("Process %d is being blocked on request",pcb->id);
            pcb->state = BLOCK_ON_ENV;
            enPQ(kernel->bq, pcb, pcb->priority);
            k_process_switch();
        }
    }else{
        kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv = kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv->nextMsgEnv;
        env->nextMsgEnv = NULL;

        //clear message
        memset(env->msg, 0, MSG_SIZE);
    }
    return env;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `for(i=0; i<AVAIL_MSG_ENV_SIZE; i++){`

Comment: And, of course `while (temp->nextMsgEnv) {`

Comment: A few stray comments: (1) you should use `AVAIL_MSG_ENV_SIZE - 1` rather than `19` when the former is what you mean; (2) is `Msg` defined as a pointer type? if not, you should cast `malloc`'s return value to `Msg *`, not to `Msg`; (3) how are you initializing `temp`? (I assume `temp = kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[0]`?)

Comment: I've edited in your original question back in to keep the original context.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop-test doesn't change:

```
while (kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv) {
```

So it's iterating through 20 times, and keeps on going...

Perhaps you meant this?

```
while (kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[x].nextMsgEnv) {
```

Comment: Its now giving me a segmentation fault at 1 element...does kernel->availMsgEnvQueue[19].nextMsgEnv = NULL; make the last element 0?

Comment: If you're running this loop immediately after you initialize it in your first snippet, it shouldn't be crashing on the first element... EDIT: Have you checked which exact dereference it seg-faulting?

Comment: Its not crashing anymore...however I would be greatful if you could have a look at this code.. I've added an edit to the main post

Comment: It's in the edit of the main post. I'm getting segmentation error when i try and dequeue the last element

Comment: Can you point out where exactly it's crashing in the new code? The last element should have `->nextMsgEnv = NULL`, so it should be entering the first part of the if-statement.

Comment: @Falcata: `kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv = kernel->availMsgEnvQueue->nextMsgEnv->nextMsgEnv;` is same as `env = env->nextMsgEnv;`, so for the last element `env = evn->nextMsgEnv;` will be `env = NULL`. Just add a NULL check before operating on `env`